# Why is North Korea refusing COVID vaccine donations?

Tags: covid-19, north-korea

https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/kim-jong-un-rejects-covid-vaccine-offer-urges-north-korea-n1278445

> North Korean leader Kim Jong Un ordered officials to wage a tougher
> epidemic prevention campaign in “our style” after he turned down some
> foreign Covid-19 vaccines offered via the U.N.-backed immunization
> program.

Why would North Korea refuse the vaccines offered via an U.N. backed program? Is it because they don't trust the U.N.? Is it because of some other issues? I can't think of a good reason to refuse especially if it's free. Is it likely that they're going to accept, but not publicly in order to save face or something along that line?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The reason they gave was that the shots should be relocated to harder hit nations.](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-58408913) They have also stated before, and still maintain the position, that they [do not have any COVID cases](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/31/world/asia/north-korea-coronavirus.html). If they were to accept the shots, that would indicate to the rest of the world that they probably do have cases, enough cases for them to want the shots, indicating to the rest of the world that they may be in a more precarious position than they had originally admitted.

If they were to take the shots, they would basically be admitting that they lied about their situation (which they probably wouldn't want to do), and also tell the rest of the world that they're in a vulnerable position.

I think another reason is that they also don't trust the vaccines. They also rejected the vaccines in July, "[citing concerns over potential side effects, a South-Korean think-tank associated with the country's intelligence service said](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-58408913)". This may be the best reason because they have [allegedly shown interest in the vaccines from Russia](https://www.straitstimes.com/asia/east-asia/north-korea-rejects-offer-of-nearly-3-million-sinovac-covid-19-vaccines).

By the way, I believe that the source you linked does imply, if not state, one of the suspected reasons.

Comment: First story (BBC) says that Russia says they've also turned down Russian vaccines, multiple times.

Comment: With NK it's also possible the threat of Covid can be a useful form of extra social control, allowing even greater coercion about gathering and movement than usual.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: frankly, nobody knows what goes though the head of Kim Jong-un, so this is going to be hard to answer with anything but their official line... I mean, what's [3M dead](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-57507456) to Kim if you can have another "Arduous March"...

Comment: @Fizz Totally.  Given that Kim decides everything this question - explaining what seems to be irrational behavior - veers dangerously close to asking for internal motivations of people.  For all we know, he may be following QAnon threads too closely ;-)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: or the NK version of it. Something to do with dust clouds from China... https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-54655692

Comment: “If they were to accept the shots, that would indicate to the rest of the world that they probably do have cases” – well... no it wouldn't. All it would indicate is that they consider the _possibility that they might get_ new cases in the future (whether from outside or by transmission within the country). Of course Kim may indeed reason that even this is admitting defeat, but... yeah, nothing there really makes sense.

Comment: It's not just about what the rest of the world thinks, it's also about what its own citizens think.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that due to their lack of socialisation with the outside world and methods of dealing with confirmed infections, they may *actually* have a very low number of cases.

Comment: There is a lot of disbelief that NK actually has 0 cases but given that there isn't exactly free movement across the border I don't find it that hard to believe.

Comment: @Valorum Indeed. And the North Korean government probably doesn't see any problem in curing COVID cases with bullets or camps.

Comment: Yep, this is one of those situations where NK's self-isolation is actually very helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Because they want to tout the success of their self-isolation methods, which were strict long before COVID showed up. According to [South China Morning Post](https://archive.is/XeOQE):

> Kee Park, a lecturer at Harvard Medical School who has made numerous
> humanitarian trips to North Korea, said he believed Pyongyang wanted
> to send the message that its self-imposed isolation had kept it safe.
> “Their confidence in their public health measures also allows them to
> take a more patient approach to see what, if any, issues arise with
> these new vaccines as they get rolled out,” Park said.

Donations were similarly rejected during the 1990s famine in North Korea:

> During the 1990s, the North downplayed food shortages until a
> widespread famine that killed an estimated 240,000-3.5 million people
> forced it to seek international assistance. How will ‘emaciated’ Kim
> ride out a famine in North Korea? With China’s help 6 Jul 2021
>
> “Saving face is a strong cultural motivator for Koreans,” said Dan
> Chung, executive director of Crossing Borders, a US-based Christian
> aid group that works with North Korean refugees. “Though it seems as
> if North Koreans are reaching out for help, a moment later they could
> indicate the exact opposite. This makes helping North Korea all the
> more complex.”

As a final note, Kim Jung Un and his senior leadership are [well known](https://www.the-sun.com/news/759895/kim-jong-un-north-korea-lifestyle-palaces/) for their lavish lifestyle so we could speculate that they're all secretly vaccinated already, making them care a lot less about how many vaccines are available for the rest of their citizens.

Comment: News from a couple of months ago was that South Korean intelligence was fairly sure Kim wasn't vaccinated https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-07-09/kim-jong-un-has-not-received-vaccine-south-korea-says/100279646 although with all the luxury stuff that's smuggled to him, despite the sanctions, a vaccine would be extremely small potatoes if he wanted one.

Comment: Btw, this reminded me of the story with Latin/South America politicians getting secretly vaccinated (well ahead of the population); in Peru [at least](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/story/2021-02-18/peru-vaccine-gate-politicians-diplomats-received-chinese-vaccine), and probably not just there. [Probably](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/02/25/world/americas/covid-south-america-vaccine-corruption.html) in Brazil too, although not their president... Ecuador, Lebanon etc.

Comment: @Fizz That reminds me of a placed called the United States of America.

Answer (score -6):

Kim Jung Un's decision to refuse vaccines is difficult to explain but it is not that unusual.  Perhaps he refused vaccines for the same reasons that Trump and Morrison refused vaccines.

Comment: According to the article, the vaccine doses that rejected were primarily Chinese Sinovac with a smaller number of AstraZeneca doses.

Comment: @divibisan you are correct

Comment: Be careful with labeling some people: [Does the Be Nice policy require SE users to "be nice" to people who are not SE users (e.g. public figures)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286082/241919)

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. Trump might have initially downplayed COVID-19, but he eventually did order a government vaccination program ([operation warp-speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Warp_Speed)) and [he got vaccinated](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/donald-trump-i-got-the-pfizer-125703879.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9kdWNrZHVja2dvLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAFWyxU6hXF43tHxe87Rr0zQZNw6DQLmY5oCLf-MIRA80WbPcL8HHUYSXaLBqGBomcIFD71kW1_KyWGIQHdZhnOjgB_1YeErwgZkOlqzB2Ey3_Kcd0gdw6rBQ6pw4DSZWE70wtAitUFyEc6Yn7iW1ZffP2xvB8TgBr1GojkYtb2i7).

Comment: @Philipp I believe (but have no proof) that Kim Jung Un has also been vaccinated, but has he encouraged North Koreans to get vaccinated?  In that respect he is about the same as Trump.  https://www.snopes.com/ap/2020/12/07/feds-passed-up-chance-to-lock-in-more-pfizer-vaccine-doses/  Trump like Kim Jung Un passed up a chance to secure vaccines for his country.